# Error in qmake could not find a Qt installation of ''

Tags: qt, qmake

I found few other questions on stackoverflow but I could not understand what I needed to do.

When I try to run the qmake command I get the error

```
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

$ which qmake

/usr/bin/qmake

...............

But In Tools - Options - Qt Versions

qmake location  is /home/vegeta/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin ?

Even if I try to add path manually I get an error The Qmake is not executable

What needs to be done?

Comment: Solved     /opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake -query

Comment: Partially solved, I guess. You have two installations of Qt, and now you're forced to use the older one.